# How to convert background-position: % in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Didn't find a way to convert
`background-position: 0% 20%;`
in tailwind

I only find these classes `bg-{side}`

any help is appreciated

Comment: write your own class. I doubt it's a good idea to have a class for each percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the new just-in-time (JIT) mode, you can generate this class on the fly.

Then you can just use: `bg-[0% 20%]`. The square brackets just mean that this is an arbitrary value that isn't in the config.

Here are the docs for JIT mode.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Comment: `bg-[0% 20%]` doesn't work for me, whereas something like `w-[80px]` does.

Answer (score 6):

JIT for tailwind v3 is currently not implemented.

I was able to achieve

```
background-position: -200% 0%;
```

or

```
background-position-x: -200%;
background-position-y: 0%
```

by doing

```
bg-[left_calc(-200%)_top_calc(0%)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has a very small section at the bottom of the background-size page that shows how to do this:

`bg-[length:auto_100%]`

Will convert to `background-size: auto 100%` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like background position, background image and background size cannot accept arbitrary values, I did try on the Tailwind Play without any luck: https://play.tailwindcss.com/MkuaNCxvFs?layout=horizontal